# How do you compare two sets of list according to the an order?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem where i am given two pairs of cards and i am supposed to compare which one is higher. I tried spreading out the list, but i have no idea on how to compare. So the purpose is to find if the first pair is higher than the others; if the first pair is higher than it returns true, if its the second pair that is higher than returns false. 
This is the base code so far:

```
RANK_ORDER = '34567890JQKA2'
SUIT_ORDER = 'DCHS'
def is_higher_pair(pair1, pair2): 
  dev1 = RANK_ORDER.find(pair1[0][0]) 
  dev2 = SUIT_ORDER.find(pair1[0][1])
  dev3 = RANK_ORDER.find(pair1[1][0]) 
  dev4  = SUIT_ORDER.find(pair1[0][1])
  your_answer = False
  if dev1 > dev3:
    your_answer = True 
  if dev1 == dev3:
    if dev2 > dev4:
      your_answer = True
  return your_answer //compares the card in the first pair but i dont know how to compare two pairs.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(is_higher_pair(['AH', 'AD'], ['8D', '8S']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['JS', 'JD'], ['2D', '2S']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['6D', '6S'], ['6H', '6C']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['KH', 'KS'], ['KD', 'KC']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['0H', '0D'], ['0S', '0C']))
```

my output should consider the rank and suit so for the given operation above this should be the results:

```
True
False
True
True
False
```

i tried comparing two cards but than lost on what i was doing.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far for the `is_higher_pair()` function? Also, can you provide more information about ranks and suits, if I understand well 2 is the highest rank and S is the highest suit? Is for example 3S supposed to beat 2H?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really helpful if you can show us what you have tried and what went wrong. It would also help to put in more detail about how the pairs should be compared. Is suit more important than rank etc.

Comment: @Silveris basically, the rank and suit are in increasing power.

Comment: How are you wanting to determine highest pair? The largest total?

Comment: To expand, what makes ['AH', 'AD'] higher than ['8D', '8S']? I would imagine ['8D', '8S'] would be larger because of the '8S'? If you are unsure I can give an answer based on assumption

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the solution, posting here:

```
RANK_ORDER = '34567890JQKA2'
SUIT_ORDER = 'DCHS'
def is_higher_pair(pair1, pair2):
  Rank1 = RANK_ORDER.find(pair1[0][0]) 
  Rank2 = RANK_ORDER.find(pair2[0][0]) 
  your_answer = False
  if Rank1 > Rank2:
    your_answer = True
  if Rank1 == Rank2:
    SuitPair1C1 = SUIT_ORDER.find(pair1[0][1])
    SuitPair1C2 = SUIT_ORDER.find(pair1[1][1])
    if SuitPair1C1 == 3 or SuitPair1C2 == 3:
      your_answer = True
  return your_answer


if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(is_higher_pair(['AH', 'AD'], ['8D', '8S']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['JS', 'JD'], ['2D', '2S']))
```

Comment: @Silveris this is the function i wanted and it works and i got it marked and it worked correct.

Comment: Alright then! I guess I did not understand the question properly. Please feel free to accept your answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well how to compare pairs, this code produces the right output:

```
RANK_ORDER = '34567890JQKA2'
SUIT_ORDER = 'DCHS'

class Pair:
  def __init__(self, card1, card2):
    # Get rank value of the pair
    v1 = RANK_ORDER.find(card1[0])
    v2 = RANK_ORDER.find(card1[0])
    self.rank_value = v1 + v2

    # Get highest suit value of the pair
    v1 = SUIT_ORDER.find(card1[1])
    v2 = SUIT_ORDER.find(card2[1])
    self.suit_value = max([v1, v2])

def is_higher_pair(pair1, pair2):
  p1 = Pair(pair1[0], pair1[1])
  p2 = Pair(pair2[0], pair2[1])

  if p1.rank_value > p2.rank_value:
    return True
  elif p1.rank_value == p2.rank_value and \
       p1.suit_value > p2.suit_value:
    return True
  return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(is_higher_pair(['AH', 'AD'], ['8D', '8S']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['JS', 'JD'], ['2D', '2S']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['6D', '6S'], ['6H', '6C']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['KH', 'KS'], ['KD', 'KC']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['0H', '0D'], ['0S', '0C']))
```

EDIT: A shorter version to achieve this (without a `Pair` class) would be:

```
def get_rank_value(pair):
  return RANK_ORDER.find(pair[0][0]) + RANK_ORDER.find(pair[1][0])

def get_suit_value(pair):
  return max([SUIT_ORDER.find(pair[0][1]), SUIT_ORDER.find(pair[1][1])])

def is_higher_pair(pair1, pair2):
  if get_rank_value(pair1) > get_rank_value(pair2):
    return True
  elif get_rank_value(pair1) == get_rank_value(pair2) and \
       get_suit_value(pair1) > get_suit_value(pair2):
    return True
  return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(is_higher_pair(['AH', 'AD'], ['8D', '8S']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['JS', 'JD'], ['2D', '2S']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['6D', '6S'], ['6H', '6C']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['KH', 'KS'], ['KD', 'KC']))
  print(is_higher_pair(['0H', '0D'], ['0S', '0C']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RANK_ORDER = '34567890JQKA2'
SUIT_ORDER = 'DCHS'

def rank(card):
    return RANK_ORDER.find(card[0])


def suit(card):
    return SUIT_ORDER.find(card[1])


def is_higher_pair(pair1, pair2):
    if rank(pair1[0]) != rank(pair2[0]):
        # return True if pair1 has the highest rank
        return rank(pair1[0]) > rank(pair2[0])
    # return True if pair1 has the highest suit
    return suit(max(pair1, key=suit)) > suit(max(pair2, key=suit))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(is_higher_pair(["AH", "AD"], ["8D", "8S"]))
    print(is_higher_pair(["JS", "JD"], ["2D", "2S"]))
    print(is_higher_pair(["6D", "6S"], ["6H", "6C"]))
    print(is_higher_pair(["KH", "KS"], ["KD", "KC"]))
    print(is_higher_pair(["0H", "0D"], ["0S", "0C"]))
```

i think this is the function op wants, it minimizes comparisons. it does assume that a pair is a valid pair and that cards are unique